# How to copy all files with a [Dot]something to a flash drive using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can I copy all files that have a [dot]something to a flash dirve using a batch file? For example, c all file on the computer that have the file extension .txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't really belong on this site... but assuming your drive is D:\

```
copy C:\Path\To\Copy\From\*.txt D:\
```

Comment: Sorry, but this only copys files that are in the same dictionary! D:

Comment: Then specify the path... see revised answer

Answer (score 0):

When doing it directly on the command line, it's just:

`for /r %x in (*.txt) do copy "%x" F:\`

Assuming that `F:\` is your flash drive, and that you start at the root of the directory tree containing those text files.  In other words, if you're in `C:\test` it will find every text file in there or any subfolder and copy those to `F:\`  So you might want to create a batch file like:

```bat
@echo off
c:
cd \wherever\the\text\files\are
for /r %%x in (*.txt) do copy "%%x" F:\
```

(EDIT:  Oops.  Have to double the %s when in a batch file.)

Comment: `cd /D \wherever\the\text\files\are` - to switch the drive if it's needed

Comment: More like `cd /D C:\wherever\the\text\files\are` :)  Not much use using the `/D` switch without specifying an actual drive letter.